# Resolving issue with SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simple-injector

Being fairly new to SimpleInjector, this could be relatively simple.

I am registering a pairing as follows;

```
container.Register<INote, Note>();
```

As per the SimpleInjector documentation. Carrying on it says to use the following to resolve this;

```
INote note = container.GetInstance<INote>();
```

However, i'm not allowed to access the properties or methods of the note variable, it just states that it is inaccessible due to it's protection level.

Within INote declared as

```
int userID;
```

within Note : INote

```
public int userID {get; set;}
```

What do I need to do to be able to resolve the INote note variable to the concrete implementation declared in the container?

Edit - More Info

The error is during compilation saying

> Error  1   'NotesDAL.Interfaces.Models.INote.userID' is inaccessible due to its protection level

The Note class is public

```
public class Note : INote
{
    public string noteID {get; set; }
    public string userID { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When do you get the error message during compilation or runtime? Can you post the full error message? Are you sure that the `Note` class itself is `public` or it is in the same project? Can you please post the full definition of the `Note` class?

Comment: Please also post your `INote` definition!

Comment: Thankyou for these comments!

Turns out I was declaring the INote interface as a class, not an interface, I knew it would be a stupid mistake but caught thanks to you!

Everything else is working perfectly!

Comment: It seems that you are defining an interface for a class that has no behavior. Interfaces are for abstracting behavior,  not data. Ditch the interface and don't resolve Note from the container. You can simply new that instance up without a container.

Comment: For the sake of this question I simplified what I am actually doing, I can assure you that the class is an implementation based on abstracting behaviour.

Comment: @EverythingGeek: In that case, you're mixing data and behavior.  Those must be separated. Saves you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Please read http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Completion;

Thankyou for these comments! Turns out I was declaring the INote interface as a class, not an interface, I knew it would be a stupid mistake but caught thanks to you! Everything else is working perfectly!